# How to force c++ compiler use one of different installed package's versions, using CMake?

Tags: c++, opencv, compilation, cmake, ros

ROS Fuerte I installed on my machine uses opencv 2.2. I would like to use 2.4.9 version just installed. Its location is `/home/polar/soft/lib/opencv/opencv-2.4.9/build/lib`.

How to do that with CMake, please?
From my search, it seems that `find_library` would solve the issue, but was not able to make it work.

===== I include opencv in my cpp codes like this

```
  #include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
    #include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
    #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
    #include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
```

=========== HERE MY CMAKE

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
include($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake)

rosbuild_init()
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

rosbuild_genmsg()
rosbuild_gensrv()


# GSL
find_package( PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules( gsl REQUIRED gsl )

SET(corners_opencv_flag ok)

#*******************************************************************
#*******************************************************************

#******                CORNERS OPENCV

#*******************************************************************
#*******************************************************************
if(corners_opencv_flag)

  #---
  SET(execFiles_corner_opencv
    corner_v1

    )

  #---
  foreach(file_ros ${execFiles_corner_opencv})
    rosbuild_add_executable(${file_ros} computer-vision/corners/${file_ros}.cpp ) 
  endforeach(file_ros)

  #---
endif(corners_opencv_flag)


#-------------------
# STACK 
#--------------------

SET(FILES_TO_RUN
  ${execFiles_corner_opencv} 
  )


#=======================================================
#
#     CUSTOM LIBRARIES
#
#
#=======================================================
PROJECT(VOLCANO)
SET(SRC ${VOLCANO_SOURCE_DIR}/src)


#******* boost
find_package( Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS program_options regex )
include_directories( ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

if(Boost_FOUND)
  message("\n\n Boost found \n\n")
endif()

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED PATHS /home/polar/soft/lib/opencv/opencv-2.4.9/cmake)


#===== Calculus
include_directories(${SRC}/calculus)
include_directories(${SRC}/calculus/matrix)
SET(MY_LIB
  ${MY_LIB}
 Calculus
 CholeskyDecompose
 )


#-------------------------------------------
# Linking the executables against the

#-------------------------------------------

foreach(file2link ${FILES_TO_RUN})

  target_link_libraries(${file2link} 
    ${MY_LIB} 
    ${MY_LIB} 
    ${gsl_LIBRARIES}
    ${Boost_PROGRAM_OPTIONS_LIBRARY} ${Boost_REGEX_LIBRARY}
    ${OpenCV_LIB}
   )

endforeach(file2link)  


#--- sources folders
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(src)
```

Comment: Have you tried `find_package( OpenCV 2.9 ... )`?

Comment: `find_package(OpenCV 2.4.9 PATHS /home/polar/soft/lib/opencv/opencv-2.4.9/cmake)` does not work. Compilation error.

Comment: 1) You said you want to use version 2.9...? 2) "Compilation error"?

Comment: Sorry, I need 2.4.9.

Comment: "Compilation error"? Come on. You must *realize* that the information you're giving is in no way sufficient to give you any kind of assistance...

Comment: I get undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)`. The same error message related to the opencv functions am using.

Comment: That is a **linker** error, not a compilation error. I see you have `${OpenCV_LIB}` in there... but you only ever set that for `corner_v1`, and only `if ( corners_opencv_flag )` -- which you set to `ok`. But `if ( condition )` is true "*if the constant is 1, ON, YES, TRUE, Y, or a non-zero number*" -- note the absence of `ok`. And I'd check if `${OpenCV_LIB}` is set as expected in the first place...

Comment: the flag ok is only for the executables not the libraries. I suspect `OpenCV_LIB`

Comment: Voting to close as "unclear what you're asking". Pal, my crystal ball is failing to make sense of the little tidbits you're willing to share. Either you accept that something **is** broken in your setup, and cooperate with people willing to invest *their* time into helping you (including double-checking your assumptions on what's working and what isn't), or you'll have to figure it out yourself.

Comment: @devSolar I followed this link to install opencv [http://www.samontab.com/web/2014/06/installing-opencv-2-4-9-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts/] I will try to reinstall it from a different link and see what happen.

Comment: P.S. am using ubmuntu 12.04 LTS.

Comment: How is that supposed to help with your CMakeLists.txt apparently not adding the OpenCV libraries to whatever target you are trying to compile? If it hadn't **found** OpenCV, it would have failed at config stage due to the `REQUIRED` in `find_package`. Stop hunting what you *think* might be the error and go for *proof*. *Check your assumptions.* Or start actually answering the questions asked, instead of continuing an unrelated monologue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, as I suspected,  `target_link_libraries(${file2link}  .... ${OpenCV_LIB})`
was the problem: `OpenCV_LIB` seems like allocated.

Now, am linking opencv in this way and it works:

```
find_package(OpenCVV 2.4.9 PATHS /home/polar/soft/lib/opencv/opencv-2.4.9/cmake)
...
target_link_libraries(${file2link}  .... ${OpenCVV_LIB})
```

In fact I just used another name but `OpenCV`.

@texasflood, thanks for your help.

Comment: Is this a typo? `OpenCVV_LIB`

Comment: Yes, It is `OpenCV_LIBS`

Answer (score 7):

Add this to your CMakeLists.txt replacing the previous `find_package(OpenCV)` line:

```
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED PATHS /home/polar/soft/lib/opencv/opencv-2.4.9/cmake)
```

There should be a cmake directory in your opencv installation.

Comment: The compiler still uses opencv from ROS, tough I commented the manigfest line including opencv.

Comment: Can you post your full CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: Worked for me (CMake 2.8.12.2 and OpenCV 3.2.0 on Ubuntu 12.4). I added it as an answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37336667

Answer (score 1):

There is lot of confusion here and No Proper Code to solidify the suggestions.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

project( DisplayImage )

# Enable C++11
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED TRUE)

# For OpenCV 4
SET(OpenCV_DIR <current-path>/Learning/opencv-installation/installation/OpenCV-master/lib/cmake/opencv4)

# For OpenCV 3
# SET(OpenCV_DIR "<current-path>/opencv3.4.8/installation/OpenCV-3.4.8/share/OpenCV/")

# If the package has been found, several variables will
# be set, you can find the full list with descriptions
# in the OpenCVConfig.cmake file.
# Print some message showing some of them
message(STATUS "OpenCV library status:")
message(STATUS "    version: ${OpenCV_VERSION}")
message(STATUS "    libraries: ${OpenCV_LIBS}")
message(STATUS "    include path: ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}")

find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
add_executable( DisplayImage main.cpp )
target_link_libraries( DisplayImage ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

Thank you.