# Set Opencv path for a c++ project using Cmake

Tags: opencv, cmake

I have two Opencvs, opencv-2.4.10 is installed in /usr and opencv-3.1 is installed in /usr/local. I can set the opencv path in Eclipse easily. In cmake, how can I set the path for one of the opencvs I like to use for that project?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force c++ compiler use one of different installed package's versions, using CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28507214/how-to-force-c-compiler-use-one-of-different-installed-packages-versions-usi)

Answer (score 11):

This question is a duplicate of [How to force c++ compiler use one of different installed package's versions, using CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28507214/how-to-force-c-compiler-use-one-of-different-installed-packages-versions-usi) but it is found by search engines so I add the [answer from texasflood](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28510128/4669135) that I found to be working with CMake 2.8.12.2 and OpenCV 3.2.0 on Ubuntu 12.4:

Simply change the `find_package` command:

```
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED PATHS "/usr/opencv-2.4.10")
```

Answer (score 6):

None of the other answers worked for me (linux, opencv 4.0.0, haven't tested yet with opencv 3.x.x).

Adding the following before the line `find_package(...)` in the CMakeLists.txt  worked:

```
set(OpenCV_DIR /path/to/opencv_install_dir/lib/cmake/opencv4)
```

If opencv was compiled from source with a none standard installation target directory, then `/path/to/opencv_install_dir` is (should be) known, otherwise search for the location of the directory structure `lib/cmake/opencv*`.

Comment: You might need to add double quotations for the dir path as below:                                                `set(OpenCV_DIR "/path/to/opencv_dir/)"`

Answer (score 4):

I don't have a Linux machine to test it on but this is how I do it on Windows 10 64bit.

I only added a line in the `CmakeLists.txt` in my program to set the variable `OpenCV_DIR` used by CMake.

For example, if OpenCV is installed in `C:/opencv`, I add

```
SET("OpenCV_DIR" "C:/opencv")
```

in my `CMakeLists.txt`.

In your case, it should be something like

```
SET("OpenCV_DIR" "/usr/opencv-2.4.10")
```

But, as I said, I never tested this on Linux.

Comment: No not yet. I set as SET("OpenCV_DIR" "/usr/share/OpenCV"). But it doesn't link.

Comment: @batuman  Make sure you also have the lines: find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED), include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}) and 
target_link_libraries(Program ${OpenCV_LIBS}) in your CMakeLists. Otherwise it's not going to do anything

Comment: Make sure also, that the directory you specified is the directory where OpenCV is built, not the sources.

Comment: Did not work for me (CMake 2.8.12.2, OpenCV 3.2.0, Ubuntu 12.4), see my answer instead.